# Is it possible to use Sharepoint API in an external app/website?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory

I have used the SharePoint REST API to upload the files to SharePoint but, I have been wondering if it is possible to use the Sharepoint API inside my website to make it seamless.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s possible and that is what we call “SharePoint headless”, meaning using SP as a backend only.

You will need a service account / token to interact with SP API from your website.

Comment: Can you please provide the official documentation, so far I have searched, and it is only possible to get sites, and lists using graph API, but for my application, I need to add, update and delete files on a SharePoint library.

Comment: If you want to use Graph API you need to look at "driveitem" endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
You can also use the SharePoint REST API with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest